cannot convert from 'string' to 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader'CS1503 error showing up how to i convert to newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader?
I was trying to retrive information from a json file and save it to mapCollision and layers
but CS1503 error showing up
the json file includes 2 jagged arrays which represent a map
{
    "layer":[
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["|","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","  ","|"],
        ["--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--","--"]]
    ,"collision":[
        [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
    ]
}

and the code
public class Map{
  public string[][] layer {get; set;}
  public int[][] collision {get; set;}
}

Console.Write(dir+@"maps\map1.json");
Console.ReadKey();
string hol = File.ReadAllText(dir+@"maps\map1.json");
Map jsonMap = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Map>(hol)!;// error showing up under hol telling me i cant convert from string to Newtonsoft.Json
mapCollision = jsonMap.collision;
layers = jsonMap.layer;

I was trying to deserialsize the json file at dir
its just giving me a error code
I have tried to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() but it gives me this error codeCannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'HelloWorld.Map'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)CS0266

Do you mean you used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(json) rather than JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Map>(json); or did you just use the non-generic method?

oh mb the Map varible is a class i created

JsonSerializer.Deserialize is the syntax for using the System.Text.Json library. If you want to do that, then add using System.Text.Json; and remove any reference to Newtonsoft. For example:
using System.Text.Json;
...

var jsonMap = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Map>(hol);

If you want to use Newtonsoft then you need to add using Newtonsoft.Json; and change your code to use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. Example:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
...

var jsonMap = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Map>(hol);


ill give it a try tks
